# Applying jQuery AJAX load() method for asynchronous loading of page content on an existing PHP website

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a small rental car business and have an existing PHP website that presents our fleet and accepts online reservations using a series of PHP pages and SQL database calls. The system works very well, however I would like users to be able to move between pages of the website without the browser going to the usual blank page in between.

I have made an attempt at using AJAX to asynchronously load content of the pages in question into a "container" page, however I have not been successful in achieving the required result. The pages are heavy with PHP code and when I attempt to load content asynchronously using AJAX I get load issues that I cannot seem to resolve.

I understand that the AJAX load() method allows content to be asynchronously loaded into a container such as a DIV element, however I am wanting to know if this method can be applied to the full page content. In a sense, the full  of the page would be the container for the content of each page to be loaded into.

Ideally, each separate page would load in the background with a semi-transparent loader overlay (like an animated moving loader bar) would sit over the current page, and the target page would be loaded and then the overlay removed to fully reveal the new page content. The user would see the loader overlaying the current page content, then would see the new page content without seeing a blank page in-between.

Can the AJAX load() method somehow be applied to the full page rather than to a DIV, and would there be an effective way to apply this method to some or all existing pages without a large amount of rework to the existing page content?

Many thanks,
Scott.

Comment: From the documentation, I would expect you could get your desired behavior by wrapping the target page output (everything between body tags) in a div, targeting that div, and overwriting/filling a div in your current page. That being said, my gut feeling is this is not a good long term solution; ajax (IMHO) should always use json, not html. `load()` seems like a quick and dirty, hacky fix to me. (But I’ve also never used it; YMMV)

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim. I will look further into using JSON for this as you have suggested. Cheers, Scott.